# How can I extract an AVMetadataObject from a UIImage?

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation, barcode, avcapturesession

I'd like to use iOS 7's new barcode scanning functionality with a `UIImage` instead of live capture from one of the device's camera. I already have the detection working fine with an `AVCaptureDeviceInput`.

The best way I think to do this would be to create a concrete subclass of `AVCaptureInput` that provides media data to an `AVCaptureSession` from a `UIImage`. However, I can't find any documentation or examples on how to subclass `AVCaptureInput`, so I'm at a loss.

An alternative would be to override the media stream from an existing `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, but since those API's are private and I'd like to publish my app on the App Store, this isn't ideal.

Ultimately, I'll likely end up doing this using a 3rd party barcode library like ZXing or ZBar, but it seems like a waste to not be able to use Apple's built-in functionality here.

Comment: FYI, I submitted an Apple Developer Technical Support request with this question and Apple stated that this can't be done and to file a radar if it's desired functionality.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I ended up using ZBar. Neither iOS 7 or iOS 8 support this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How do I "file a radar" to also request this?

Comment: @StanJames bugreport.apple.com

Comment: does this help https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html?

Answer (score 0):

life is easy.
You can use CIDetector instead.
Convert an image into CIImage to be decoded by CIDetector.