# Reading QRCode from CameraRoll using AVFoundation - iOS 7

Tags: ios7

Someone know how to read a QRCode from iPhone camera roll using AVFoundation. I've already google it, but can't find an answer to how accomplish that.

Does anybody have any idea of how doing that?

Need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this can't be done at this time.

See this SQ question: [How can I extract an AVMetadataObject from a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480466/how-can-i-extract-an-avmetadataobject-from-a-uiimage)